# Video as background on a website playing on command

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, html5-video

I've been trying to set a video as background, I have the flv-file and youtube-link. Putting it on my website isn't that difficult with html5 video-tag or jquery but I can't find how I can put it on my website but not auto starting. I have a semi-transparent rectangle where the text will come over. So my idea was creating a button or link to let the text and rectangle dissappear and letting the video play.

Does anyone knows a good plugin or script to do this or can someone bump into the right direction.

greetz

Comment: can you show us what you've got already? If you are using `<video>` tag then it should not auto play your video unless you use `autoplay` attribute...

Comment: At the moment i have the video at the top and below that the rest of my site xs, i can't seem to put the video as background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with native browser html5 video player too which will be much faster, no need to use a plugin. Try this:

**[Here is working jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/YZT5s/117/)**

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowH =  $(window).height();
    $('#main_container, #overlay').height(windowH);
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var windowH =  $(window).height();
        $('#main_container, #overlay').height(windowH);
    });
});​
```

css:

```
body { background-color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;
       color: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#main_container { float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                  background-color: #000000; }
#video { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; min-height: 100%;
         min-width: 100%; z-index: 9997; }​
#overlay { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;
           z-index: 9998; }
```

html:

```
<div id="main_container">
<div id="overlay"></div>
<video id="video" width="" height="" controls="controls" loop="loop" autoplay="">
 <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

Note: Used overlay div for deactivating controls and you can use whatever content on your video, like in jsFiddle example.

Comment: Thanks, i'm getting further now. And letting the rectangle with the text dissappear shall i just use a jquery/js command to set the visibility to hidden? or something

Comment: you can manipulate content area with CSS. no need jQuery over there. i used jQuery for setting wrapper's (main_container's) area to prevent css conflict.

Comment: I got it too work now :), only issue i have left is that i can't seem to increase the height of the window and content.

Comment: you can change that values from variation. example: var windowH = $(window).height() +10;

Comment: It doesn't give the result i want. I want to increase the height of the content part and keep the video on the same spot. 

as you can see on the image below, the boxes continue under the page however i can't get scrollbars or increase the height

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/94047586.png/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15184/discussion-between-jochemke-and-barlasapaydin)

Comment: than remove css overflow:hidden; from body. sorry got to go, need to eat something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script, you can try: https://github.com/sydlawrence/jquery.videoBG

In the documentation here: http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/index.html#documentation, there seems to be an auto play option with a Boolean parameter...so I'm guessing just set it to false

autoplay
    bool