# HTML: video z-index not working

Tags: html, image, video, overlay, z-index

I'm trying to get the image to show up over the video, but it's not even appearing under the video. There's some blank space in the upper left-hand corner, but the image isn't appearing there either. The image only shows up when I take the HTML code of the video out.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    #sampleVideo {
        position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1;
    }

    #sampleImage {
        z-index: 40;
    }

</style>

<body>
<video id="sampleVideo" src="sample.mp4" autoplay/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    video = document.getElementById("sampleVideo");
</script>

<img id="sampleImage" src="enter site.png">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388537/html5-video-ignoring-z-index

Answer (score 1):

You can only set `z-index` on non-static elements.

Try this:

```
#sampleImage {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how would I go about putting the image over the video?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If the z-index on your image is greater than the z-index of the video, the image should show in front.

Answer (score 1):

Dhira is correct, but you're also missing a closing video  tag. I added that on the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SF66f/3/

```
#sampleImage {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;
}
```