# Float html 5 video element in another video element

Tags: html, css, html5-video

Is there a way to float an html 5 video element with another video element just like in skype using just css? I want to make it look similar to an image below. [image]

Thanks to those who could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is similar to your question: [HTML5 video ignoring z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388537/html5-video-ignoring-z-index)

JSFiddle that explains how it work: http://jsfiddle.net/YZT5s/117/ (got this link from best answer of the linked stackoverflow question above)

```
^^^
```