# Computed Z-Index Does Not Match Element Style

Tags: html, css, html5-video

Currently working on an html5 video player. I am running into an issue where once the video element is fullscreen, my custom controls are not clickable due to the video's z-index being set to the max int value; the same as the controls z-index. the default browser media controls are already hidden.

```
<div id="video-container">
  <video frameborder='0' id="page-video" playsinline>
        <source src='{{source}}'>
  </video>
  <div class="container" id="player-controls">
     <!-- controls go here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the css for the video container in fullscreen:

```
#video-container {
position: relative;
max-width: 512px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

here's the css for the video in fullscreen:

```
#page-video:-webkit-full-screen {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Here is the css for the controls:

```
#player-controls {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
visibility: hidden;
transition: all .2s linear;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2147483647; 
cursor: pointer;
}
```

in the Chrome dev tools, the computed z-index for the video element is changed from auto when its NOT in fullscreen to 2147483647 however clicking on the arrow to expand, it shows the z-index: 1 !important style from my style sheet. This style is not crossed out or anything. I don't really understand why this is happening. These are the only two places in my entire style sheet that use z-index. There are no negative z-indexes anywhere.

Comment: There is no reason to ever use `2147483647` for `z-index`. Please use semantic values like `2`.

Comment: @TylerH that is the default set for the video by the user agent style sheet per both CSS-Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen and MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player

and to clarify, even while the video's z-index is set to 1, the controls will not appear unless the z-index is set to 2147483647. Even 2147483646 will cause it to disappear.

Comment: That is only the case for Safari.

Comment: @TylerH https://gyazo.com/56630933dcc7911781de75a31b5dedf2 the Chrome user agent stylesheet is doing the same for some reason unless I am reading that incorrectly.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9ab30478074481064c5547c208c493b5 this is what i see when I check computed

Comment: Why do you set the visibility of your controlls to "hidden"?

Comment: @FranzDeschler i have the visibility set to visible when the user hovers over the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video tag will ignore the z-index you set on it and use the UA styles of "auto" and 2147483647 unless you set `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` on it. See [HTML5 video ignoring z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388537/html5-video-ignoring-z-index)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the native controls, you need to disable them via the "controls" attribute.

```
<video controls="false">...</video>
```

In some browsers, there seems to be a bug so that the native controls are still visible in fullscreen mode. You can override the browsers stylesheet and hide them manually:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

To show your custom controlls, simply set the z-index to the max int value.

```
#player-controls {
    z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

All of this is described in this blog: https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/

Comment: I have already hidden the native browser controls and set the z-index.